# How to solve $\sin^{-1}(\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}) + \cos^{-1}(\cos\frac{4\pi}{3})$?

Tags: trigonometry

Ok so this the problem given in my text boo

> The principal value of $\sin^{-1}(\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}) + \cos^{-1}(\cos\frac{4\pi}{3})$ is

(A)$\frac{8\pi}{3}$      (B)$\frac{4\pi}{3}$       (C)$\frac{2\pi}{3}$     (D)$\frac{\pi}{3}$

and the following condition are given with it
for $$(x<0 )---\{\frac{-5\pi}{2}\le\sin^{-1}x<0,$$  $$\frac{\pi}{2}\le\cos^{-1}x\le\pi$$

and  for
$$(x\ge0 )---\{0\le\sin^{-1}x<\frac{\pi}{2},$$  $$0\le\cos^{-1}x\le\frac{\pi}{2}$$

However the condition were making no sense to me so i tried to solve the problem simply like this   $$\implies \sin^{-1}(\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}) + \cos^{-1}(\cos\frac{4\pi}{3})$$
$$\implies \frac{4\pi}{3} + \frac{4\pi}{3}$$ $$\implies \frac{8\pi}{3}$$  (and those little disgrace gave this answer in the option too), but this option is wrong, the answer is **D**.

So were I am making a  mistake, How do I use the condition please help me please.

Akash

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is D) because $\sin^{-1}\left(\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, hence the result.

Comment: damm i missed the negative sign (feeling embarrassed amde such a silly mistake)